# JPA/Hibernate works with Postgresql, but not with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to replace PostgreSQL in my application with MySQL. I thought that it should be sufficient to replace the `<properties>` in persistence.xml file:

PostgreSQL:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

MySQL:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="hiberante.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GoOut2"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

But with this replacement, I amg getting

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I just hoped that the replacement would be straightforward. In PostgreSQL, everything works correctly.

Persistence.xml: https://gist.github.com/2252443

applicationContext.xml: https://gist.github.com/2252463

exception: https://gist.github.com/2252487

Thanks!

EDIT: 
I remove username and password from the given code intentionally.

Comment: can you post the startup messages for the session factory as well?

Comment: can you connect from mysql workbench with the given credential information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missing configuration hibernate dialect for PostgreSQL:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
```

**EDIT:**

You have miss spelling in configuration:

```
<property name="hiberante.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GoOut2"/>
```

should be

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GoOut2"/>
```

Is `hibernate`, but not `hiberante`.

Comment: I just forgot to add it to the example, but my problem is not PostgreSQL, byt MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
```